# this error is occur when composer update in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Loading composer repositories with package information

Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Nothing to install or update

Package phpoffice/phpexcel is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use phpoffice/phpspreadsheet instead.

Generating optimized autoload files

Carbon 1 is deprecated, see how to migrate to [Carbon 2](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-carbon-2)

You can run `.\vendor\bin\upgrade-carbon` to get help in updating carbon and other frameworks and libraries that depend on it.

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
>
> ```
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
> PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Psr\Log\LoggerInterface' not found in C:\xampp7\htdocs\bll-console\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Log\LogManager.php on line 20
> PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Psr\Log\LoggerInterface' not found in C:\xampp7\htdocs\bll-console\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\Logger.php on line 28
> Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255
> ```

Comment: Try to install `psr/log`, https://packagist.org/packages/psr/log

Answer (score 2):

I just go throw by google. I hope this solve your problem by following.

```
composer global update
```

and then

```
composer update
```

Reference: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/22003